# PHP upload multiple files with random name

Tags: php, file-upload

I got problem to set file name when uploading the image using multiple input file.

```
<span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
    Browse <input type="file" name="image[]" id="image" class="image" onchange="preview_image();" multiple/>
</span>
```

And here is the PHP:

```
$total = count($_FILES['image']['name']);

for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++)
{
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i];

    if($tmpFilePath != "")
    {
        $info1 = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'][$i]);
        $ext = $info1['extension'];
        $newname1 = "CALIBRATION_.".$ext; 

        $newFilePath = "../assets/img/product/" . $newname1[$i];

        if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)){}
    }
}
```

When I try to run the code, it show me wrong name & type. You can see below screenshot.

[image]

What I want is to rename the file after uploaded with correct name and file type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You access $newname1 as an array, this is not what you want. Plus, you are missing the random of your name.

try doing

```
$total = count($_FILES['image']['name']);

for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++)
{
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i];

    if($tmpFilePath != "")
    {
        $info1 = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'][$i]);
        $ext = $info1['extension'];
        $newname1 = "CALIBRATION_" . rand(10000,99999) . "." . $ext; 

        $newFilePath = "../assets/img/product/" . $newname1;

        if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)){}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `[$i]` from this line `$newname1[$i]`. this will create an array of string so the name of the file will be a single character. add `rand()` or put any unique number to get unique name for the file

```
    $newname1 = "CALIBRATION_".rand(1000, 9999).".".$ext; 

    $newFilePath = "../assets/img/product/" . $newname1;
```

Answer (score 1):

`$newname1` is string not an array. If you want to concat `$i` value with new name you can do it like following code

```
if($tmpFilePath != "")
{
    $info1 = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'][$i]);
    $ext = $info1['extension'];
    $newname1 = "CALIBRATION_".$i.".".$ext; 

    $newFilePath = "../assets/img/product/" . $newname1;

    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)){}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `[$i]` from this line to get full name and not only the `$i`th character of file name:

```
$newFilePath = "../assets/img/product/" . $newname1[$i];
```

If you want to generate new file name with original name and extension but prefixed with `CALIBRATION_.` and not a random number, you can use two versions:

```
$newname1 = "CALIBRATION_" . $info1['basename'];
// or
$newname1 = "CALIBRATION_" . $info1['filename'] . '.' . $info1['extension'];
```

> You don't need to create a variable if you only use it once, as `$ext` in your code. Here you can use `$info1`, containing `dirname`, `basename`, `filename` and `extension`